# Guice, FactoryModuleBuilder, multiple implementations, and generics

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

I am using Guice and FactoryModuleBuilder. Typically, it is enough to just define an interface of the factory and Guice will automatically inject the implementation.

However, the part that I am struggling is that the methods in a factory uses generics. Suppose I have the following. A base type of constructed instances as defined by the interface.

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T get();
}
```

And two implementations of the `Foo` interface as defined by the two classes below.

```
class FooA<T> implements Foo<T> {
    @Inject
    FooA(@Assisted Class<T> clazz, @Assisted String s) {...}
}

class FooB<T> implements Foo<T> {
    @Inject
    FooB(@Assisted Class<T> clazz, @Assisted Integer i) {...}
}
```

Then I have the factory interface as defined below, using two custom binding annotations that allows me to use multiple implementations.

```
interface FooFactory {
    @A Foo<T> build(Class<T> clazz, String s);
    @B Foo<T> build(Class<T> clazz, Integer i);
}
```

I have tried a number of possible solutions, all but one has worked so far. The solution that worked is to basically write my own implementation of `FooFactory` as shown below. And in the `configure` method of the module, bind the interface to the implementation; `bind(FooFactory.class).to(FooFactoryImpl.class);`

```
class FooFactoryImpl {
    Foo<T> build(Class<T> clazz, String s) {
        return new FooA(clazz, s):
    }
    Foo<T> build(Class<T> clazz, Integer i) {
        return new FooB(clazz, i);
    }
}
```

However, I have one issue with this solution. The instances are not created by Guice and thus I lose the null checks that comes with Guice. This is drastically different from my other factories that does not have this problem. This means I have to explicitly write null checks for every implementation of `Foo`. I would like to avoid that.

The following are some of the solutions I have tried.

Solution 1:

```
FactoryModuleBuilder fmb = new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(Foo.class, A.class, FooA.class)
    .implement(Foo.class, B.class, FooB.class);
install(fmb.build(FooFactory.class));
```

Solution 2:

```
FactoryModuleBuilder fmb = new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(TypeLiteral.get(Foo.class), A.class, TypeLiteral.get(FooA.class))
    .implement(TypeLiteral.get(Foo.class), B.class, TypeLiteral.get(FooB.class));
install(fmb.build(TypeLiteral.get(FooFactory.class)));
```

The sample code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/ChrisZhong/guice-multiple-implementations-factory) (if anyone is interested).

Comment: Do your FooA and FooB constructors have any injected instances? Should they? All I see are two @Assisted parameters, which doesn't explain how Guice is helpful here.

Comment: I don't think assisted injection works when the factory methods themselves are generic.  But if you make it `FooFactory<T>` it could work.

Comment: @JeffBowman, it is a simplified example. Still, regardless if the constructors have any Guice auto-injected instances, you still want Guice to manage these new instances within its own container. Plus, you get the free null checks :)

Comment: @TavianBarnes, that would mean the number of factories I have to get would be large. e.g., `FooFactory<String> f1`, `FooFactory<Integer> f2`, `FooFactory<Double> f3`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't design AssistedInject factories to work in this way. However, it seems to me you're doing too much in one class. Because you have no restrictions on `Class<T>`, it's clear you aren't using any methods of this class *in the constructor*, which means, it should be fairly easy to refactor the behavior into a separate class. I know this is a little bit of boilerplate, it's not exactly what you want, but it might look something like this:

```
interface FooDataFactory {
    @A FooData build(String s);
    @B FooData build(Integer i);
}

public class FooA<T> implements Foo<T> {
    public FooA(FooData data) {
        // You should know what class you need when you're actually calling the constructor.
        // This way you don't even need to pass around Class<T> instances
    }
}
```

If this approach doesn't work for your use case, let me know and I'll edit to compensate.

Comment: Is FooData an interface or a concrete class? And how does it help Guice to create instances of Foo?

Comment: `FooData` is a concrete class. **You** would actually create instances of Foo using `new`.

Comment: That seems to be an equivalent solution to providing an implementation of FooFactory (e.g., FooFactoryImpl) that I have in the question.